# How to create entity class dynamically in Symfony

Tags: xml, symfony, entity

I want to create entities in Symfony without going through the console and the command to then display them in the `easyadmin`. I import an `XML` file of users, groups, ... With the exec function I can pass the exec command `exec('php bin / console doctrine: database: create')`

But I cannot add the properties. I am a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the community; When asking questions details the steps you have taken and the errors you have seen on the way. Also make sure to add the code of your  functions/xml and detail the versions of the stuff you are using  (PHP, Symfony, Doctrine, Operating system, ... )

Answer (score 0):

The make entity command is one quick method to create one php class with properties with the getters and setters. After you run make migration to create the sql query and last you run the migration to run the query and pass it in the database.

You can make one command on your one to do whatever you like for more information look [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) .

Answer (score 0):

Hello finally I will create the entities by hand one by one. Thank you. Cordially.